# How Do I get into the castle walls?

Tags: candy-box-2

I already have the pink and red leather gloves, the armor, the crown, and the monkey's staff (and they're all enchanted). Regardless of how many health potions I use, I always die. Help!

Answer (score 9):

Try using Squeeze. It lets you run under the horses, so you don't have to kill all the knights.

Comment: I wish I had thought of that... I ended up using demons and spamming health pots.

Answer (score 0):

I used the teleport spell to skip over the first rider, then used the turtle potion once I got to the gate. Between the armor, fireballs, summoned octopus warriors, and the turtle shell, it became possible to get through with <1,000 HP.

Answer (score 0):

I used rocket boots and jumped over the knights and the wall.  Very easy (once I actually had the rocket boots).